# Datatable horizontal scroll bar when no data

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

i'm not getting horizontal scrolling if there is no data in the table. The columns just get cut off. Since the the table have more then 25 column, have to show the horizontal scroll bar, if no data also.

It good if have data.[image]

Comment: Have you found solution of this issue, As I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to have ngx-datatable inside a div with predefined width, height and scroll bar ie. overflow - auto (defined in css class and used conditionally in case of no data available for ngx-datatable).

If needed in ngx-datatable itself, we might need to write customize code to alter the ngx-datatable library and use in the project, but that will add an overhead eachtime when we update the library.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit, AfterViewChecked } from         　　'@angular/core';
@Directive({
selector: '[emptyRow]'
})
export class EmptyRowDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
    textElement: any;
    actionElement : any;
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, 
        private hostElement: ElementRef) {
    }

ngOnInit() {
    this.hostElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('datatable-body')[0].addEventListener("scroll", event => {
        this.hostElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('datatable-header')[0].scrollLeft = event.srcElement.scrollLeft;
    });
}

ngAfterViewChecked(){
    if (this.hostElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('empty-row').length != 0){
 　　　this.hostElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('empty-row')[0].style.width = this.hostElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('datatable-row-center')[0].style.width;
　　}
}
```

}

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer